# Is there a way to change the permissions required for a Stored Procedure via mysqlworkbench?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a stored procedure with MYSQL for Visual Studio2019. I wrote a little "stub" just to make sure that I can develop it before I start writing the real code.

I have connected to the database (it is up on RDS) and I can see it in the Server Explorer. When I try debugging it with Debug Mysql Routine I get an Error while debugging. Access denied you need SUPER, SYSTEM...

So I see I can do this with GRANT EXECUTE...  But where do I run this? I don't have access to a CLI on the RDS server? Is there some way to set this up in either Mysql for benchVS2019 or in Mysql Workbench?

Comment: Every gui can do it if the user has the privileges

Comment: I think the answer might be to get into the docker container and then run mysql and then GRANT ALL PRIVILIGES. But When I type GRANT inside the container I get GRANT not found. So I tried mysql in the container and it was not found ether.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this myself. I first needed to load mysql onto the EC2 instance I am using. Once I did that I was able to GRANT PRIVILEGES.